# Tkinter Update intvar in label

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to have an integer to constantly change inside a label using Tkinter.

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
var  = tkinter.IntVar()

label  = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=var)
button = tkinter.Button(root, command=lambda: var.set(var.get() + 1), text='+1')

label.pack()
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The closest I have come to what I need after searching is to the example above. However you need to click a button for the integer to change, What I need is without anything for the user to do, for the integer to change.

I have an array which is constantly getting bigger while the program is running which I need to print its length each time there is one new element appended to it.

Update: Working answer:

```
import tkinter
import time
root = tkinter.Tk()
var  = tkinter.IntVar()

label  = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=var)
label.pack()
def update_Value():
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        var.set(i)
        root.update()
root.after(0, update_Value)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So you whan to change after 1 hour or 1 ms or in your birthday or what. Alway there is some condition.

Comment: No, I have already a working program that I want to do an interface for, this program has number variables I need to constantly show in the interface without printing each one on a new line which is what I am doing now.

Comment: I need to change it without clicking a button.

Comment: so instead `print()` use `var.set()`

Comment: I don't have a working sample so I remove the button variable and add some time sleep then a var.set(5) before root.mainloop() right? I don't see the label changing gradually to 5

Comment: You can't use sleep - because GUI doesn't work this way. `mainloop` starts everything - if you use `var.set(5)` before `mainloop` then `mainloop` display only `5`. You have to use `after()` to run function after `mainloop` starts.

Comment: Give an example of using after function

Comment: see link in my answer.

Comment: Look at the trial I did in the thread. Either after mainloop or before it, your suggestion didn't work. Please give something that works...!

Comment: If you run before `mainloop` then you get only last result - it will be executed before tkinter shows window. If you run after `mainloop` then it will be executed after you close window. You have to run it when `mainloop` is working. You need to use `after` to add function to special list and `mainloop` will execute it.

Comment: see your example in my answer

Comment: I have added a working sample in my thread now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `root.after(time_in_milisecond, function_name)` to call function which change value in label without user interaction.

Example: [showing current time using after](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/tkinter/timer-using-after/clock-function.py)

---

Here's an example of the code from the question, using `after` to automatically call the function after `mainloop` starts:

```
import tkinter
import time
root = tkinter.Tk()
var  = tkinter.IntVar()

label  = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=var)
label.pack()

def function():
    for i in range(5):
        var.set(i)
        root.update()
        time.sleep(1) # to slow down

root.after(1, function)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't have a function which changes values, I have an array which is constantly getting bigger while the program is running which I need to print its length each time there is one new element appended to it....

Comment: But probably you have function which change array size - so add `var.set()` in this function.

Comment: Yes I have tried, the program is waiting until it finishes then it sets only the last value. for example try a while loop with different var.set() while incrementing with some time sleep inside. I see only the last value

Comment: `mainloop` does everything in GUI - ie. it updates widgets on screen. When you run some loop then `mainloop` has no control and can't update values on screen. You have to use `root.update()` after `var.set()` to let `mainloop` update widgets on screen.

Comment: do I do this after or before mainloop?

Comment: Look at the trial I did in the thread. Either after mainloop or before it, your suggestion didn't work. Please give something that works...!

Comment: It is unclear what "your answer" is supposed to represent. It looks like you just copied the code from the question. Did you change something? If so, you might want to explain what you changed.

Comment: @BryanOakley OP first showed example without `after` asking why it doesn't work but now I see OP changed example - OP put working answer. I changed my answer.